# Python Data Types and set, bool, hex

Tags: python

I´m learning (or trying) Python. So, I´m making my notes.
In all the books and web-pages appear that Python has 5 Data Types:

Numbers: number, float and "decimal" + "fraction"

String

List

Tuple

Dictionary

But... And here is my doubt... **Aren´t**

SETS: set("Hello"),

BOOL: bool(True)

and

OCTAL/HEX/BINARY (like 0x9ff)

**Data Types...?**

Yes... Is not about code, but I want to have a good understanding.
Thanks!

Comment: There are a few others worth a mention too.  frozenset, NoneType, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SETS: Arguably a new datatype, yes.  But the implementation is basically the same as a dictionary, however without any *values* only the *keys*.  It was added to python more recently, perhaps your reference material is older.

BOOL: It's really just a subclass of `int`, with 1 equal to True and 0 equal to False.

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 0 == False
True
>>> issubclass(bool, int)
True
```

OCTAL/HEX/BINARY: Just different representations of number datatypes.

```
>>> 0b1 == 0x1 == 0o1 == 1
True
```